# 2010 Workflows not working in 2016 beta

Tags: workflow, error, 2016

I working in a SharePoint site running on the 2016 beta, and I seem unable to create any of the SP 2010 workflows (approval, collect feedback, collect sigs). I have the Manage Lists permissions and even the site admin cant create a workflow based on the 2010 templates. Every time I try to create one of those workflows, I get the following error:
[image]

Does anyone else know about this issue?

Comment: try to install the RTM version. which released last month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the RTM version of [SharePoint Server 2016](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493). The message that you're receiving is pretty clear -- the product has expired.

Comment: My admin seemed to think that the RTM version wasn't available to us yet. Is it released?

Comment: The RTM Trial is available at the above link. Note that you cannot upgrade to RTM from Beta 2, you will need to do a fresh install. Also note that while it is RTM, it is not Generally Available (GA). This means you cannot purchase a license yet. Expect that to be sometime after April.